# Save the multiselect options in database

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, module, database, products

We created some "Brands" [values] in backend.

[image]

We have around 10 products in one category with category id = "40".

if we open any brand,  we are displaying all those category products as multi-select option as below image.

[image]

but when we select options and click on "save", its not working.

why we want to save is , if we select particular Brand we want to display selected Products in dropdown in frontend as below [image](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases)

[image]

Below code for displaying list of products in multi-select box.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(40)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categorylist = array();
$categorylist[] = array(
    'value' => '', 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Category')
);
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $categorylist[] = array(
        'value' => $product->getEntityId(), 'label' => $product->getName()
    );
}
$fieldset->addField('category', 'multiselect',
    array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Category'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => $categorylist,
        'name' => 'category',

    ));
```

[image]

Comment: where is product column??

Comment: can you tell me in which table i need to check for the `products of category id : 40` in db

Comment: you don't need to check just edit category there will be product show that are related to that category.

Comment: please check here : http://prnt.sc/bvmw5u , let me know if this is not you are looking for

Comment: i am talking about this. look the answer

Comment: put the name of the category multiselect `'name' => 'category[]',` instead of `'name' => 'category',`

Comment: I tried that just now @Marius , but still options are not saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$postData['category']` this will be your database table column name and `$this->getRequest()->getPost('category')` your form field name.
implode function will be add `,` between the values.

```
$postData['category'] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getPost('category'));
```

add in controller.php in **saveAction**

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('brand/brand');
 $data['products'] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getPost('category')); 
        $model->setData($data);
```

Comment: i added the code after array like here : http://pasted.co/765c4f53 , correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: this code is for saving the value in database kindly add this code where you saving your values

Comment: can you please help me to find that, i have no idea about `where values are saving`. are you telling in db?

Comment: `Spacename/Mdoulename/controllers/Adminhtml/youcontroller.php` and `save` method

Comment: this is controller.php file : http://pasted.co/9961df8c , please tell me where i need to add the code in your answer

Comment: added the code kindly check and feedback

Comment: sorry, not working for me, is there anything else i need to do ?

Comment: off-course add the column in table and refresh the cache too

Comment: this is table name :`outthink_advance_brand_category` , can you please give me sql query to add the column

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp  http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php check these

Comment: I created the column name as `products` , is i need to change the column name ?

Comment: yes add the code too..

Comment: i added the column name - `products` at the end, please check : http://prnt.sc/bvo99q , added your code in controllers, still multiselect options are not saving.